# clojure - count occurrences in hashmap inside vector

Tags: clojure

Given the following vector:

```
[{:id "1" :performed [{:type "typeA"}, {:type "typeA"}, {:type "typeB"}]}, 
 {:id "2" :performed [{:type "typeB"}, {:type "typeB"}, {:type "typeB"}]}
```

How can I count the occurrences of performed types?

Expected Output:

```
[{:id "1" :typeA 2 :typeB 1}, {:id "2" :typeB "3"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets don't quite match in your example, but assuming you mean something like this

```
(def data
  [{:id "1" :performed [{:type "typeA"}, {:type "typeA"}, {:type "typeB"}]}
   {:id "2" :performed [{:type "typeB"}, {:type "typeB"}, {:type "typeB"}]}])
```

you could write

```
(mapv 
  (fn [{:keys [id performed]}]
      (->> performed
           (map (comp keyword :type))
           frequencies
           (into {:id id})))
  data)
```

to get this answer:

```
[{:id "1", :typeA 2, :typeB 1} {:id "2", :typeB 3}]
```

---

However, you could consider if another representation would serve you better. For instance

```
(->> data
 (map (juxt :id #(->> % :performed (map :type) frequencies)))
 (into {}))
```

would give the result

```
{"1" {"typeA" 2, "typeB" 1}, "2" {"typeB" 3}}
```

Comment: I like yours better :)

Comment: Thanks! It's all about the language being so expressive :)

Answer (score 0):

Your input isn't a valid data structure, I cleaned it up assuming you wanted a vector of maps, and made sure that `type` was consistently a keyword:

```
(def foo 
  [{:id "1" :performed [{:type "typeA"} {:type "typeA"} {:type "typeB"}]} 
   {:id "2" :performed [{:type "typeB"} {:type "typeB"}{:type "typeB"}]}])

(defn do-eet [vector-of-maps]
  (for [[id performed] 
        (map (juxt :id :performed) vector-of-maps)]
      (merge {:id id } 
             (frequencies (mapcat vals performed)))))

(do-eet foo)
```